# nextjs pages with getServerSideProps can not be exported

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've recently started learning and working with next.js, i've build a simple cpanel page, and it should get data on everytime the page is requested (like react's useEffect hook), so I tried using getServerSideProps, it worked fine on local dev server, but when i do npm run dev (which runs next build && next export), it starts building and then when it starts exporting it gives me this error:

`Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error Error: Error for page /: pages with getServerSideProps can not be exported. See more info here: https://err.sh/next.js/gssp-export`.

I'm really confused, I've been trying to google the problem since the last day and couldn't find anything useful, now if I don't find any solution i'll just use react's useEffect hook to fetch the props, but u know, getServerSideProps is way better as it gets the props before rendering the page which boosts the page.
this is the index.js page code:

```js
//  /pages/index.js

import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout.js";
import PanelWrapper from "../components/panel/panelWrapper.js";
import getEnrolls from "../components/fetch/fetch.js";
import { API } from "../exports/config.js";

const PanelPage = ({ all, pending, accepted }) => {
  const [allEnrolls, setAllEnrolls] = React.useState(all);
  const [pendingEnrolls, setPendingEnrolls] = React.useState(pending);
  const [acceptedEnrolls, setAcceptedEnrolls] = React.useState(accepted);

  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState("all");

  const [allPage, setAllPage] = React.useState(allEnrolls.currentPage);
  const [pendingPage, setPendingPage] = React.useState(
    pendingEnrolls.currentPage
  );
  const [acceptedPage, setAcceptedPage] = React.useState(
    acceptedEnrolls.currentPage
  );

  //some functions in here
  return (
    <Layout>
      <PanelWrapper
        all={allEnrolls}
        pending={pendingEnrolls}
        accepted={acceptedEnrolls}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const { all, pending, accepted } = await getEnrolls();
  return {
    props: {
      all,
      pending,
      accepted,
    },
  };
};

export default PanelPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that: it is not necessary to use state and assign the values from the destructured props object in PanelPage function. Your code can be shorter and cleaner.

I also made a few small changes in your `getServerSideProps` function as well.

```
import react, { useState } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout.js";
import PanelWrapper from "../components/panel/panelWrapper.js";
import getEnrolls from "../components/fetch/fetch.js";
import { API } from "../exports/config.js";

const PanelPage = ({ all, pending, accepted }) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("all");

  const [allPage, setAllPage] = useState(all.currentPage);
  const [pendingPage, setPendingPage] = useState(
    pending.currentPage
  );
  const [acceptedPage, setAcceptedPage] = useState(
    accepted.currentPage
  );

  //some functions in here
  return (
    <Layout>
      <PanelWrapper
        all={all}
        pending={pending}
        accepted={accepted}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await getEnrolls();
  const { all, pending, accepted } = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      all,
      pending,
      accepted,
    },
  };
};

export default PanelPage;
```

Comment: yeah, but i didn't show the whole code, i need to edit the state eventually, also i've solved the problem by not exporting the app, simply bcs getServerSideProps is only available in server side rendering mode, and exporting it creates a static site, thanks anyways